# How to return previous selected item in array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I created dynamic pills tabs.
And it works except for one thing.
Perhaps most important. When I remove the pills I want it back to the route that was previously opened.
I am created stackblitz example without routes page: -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/pills-tabs?file=app/app.component.html

Here is all code except router page.
Only different is in ts file 15 line of code I have routerLink="{{ tab.path }}":

```
 <mat-chip color="primary" selected [removable]="removable" (removed)="removeTab(fruit)" routerLink="{{ tab.path }}">   {{ tab.name }}     <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable" class="x-icon">  &#10006; </mat-icon>  </mat-chip
```

I want again set question. 
This is work but when I remove pills I want to return previous tab. like a route navigate to previous tab. In Vue.js it is like router.go(-1)...
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the location service:

```js
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

...

constructor(private _location: Location) {}

...

backToTheLastUrl() {
  this._location.back();
}
```

Comment: This is work good. 
But when i remove my last pills(tabs) my location return me to my previous page. 
Example tabs
Home, Contact. 
Remove Contact. 
Go  to Home tabs and page.
Remove Home ( no more tabs).
Return me on Contact.....

Comment: did you understand ??????
Example  opened tabs pills
Home, Contac, About us...
I start to remove every tabs..
When i go to last tabs and remove i will go to my second page.
Example. Home, Contact. Remove Contact. Only one tab Home. Remove last tab Home and i will go to Contact ?????????????

Comment: I think I got it. I'll do some tests later.